# PHP 2d Array Push Issue

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, array-push

I'm in a bind..

This is the output I would like;

```
Array
(
[country] => Array(
                    [0] => England
                    [1] => Channel Islands
                )
[gor] => Array(
                    [0] => North East
                    [1] => North West
                )
[parliamentaryconstituency] => Array(
                    [0] => Aldershot
                    [1] => Aldridge-Brownhills
                )
)
```

This is what I currently have;

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [country] => England
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [country] => Channel Islands
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [gor] => North East
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [gor] => North West
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [parliamentaryconstituency] => Aldershot
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [parliamentaryconstituency] => Aldridge-Brownhills
    )
)
```

My code is;

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        switch ($key)
        {
            case 'country':
                $country = Country::description($subvalue)->get()->first();
                array_push($new_input, array('country' => $country->description));
              break;                    
            case 'gor':
                $gor = Gor::description($subvalue)->get()->first();
                array_push($new_input, array('gor' => $gor->description));
              break;
            case 'parlc':
                $parliamentaryconstituency = ParliamentaryConstituency::description($subvalue)->get()->first();
                array_push($new_input, array('parliamentaryconstituency' => $parliamentaryconstituency->description));
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

I considered `array_push($new_input['country'], $country->description);` and having `$new_input['country']` above the `foreach`s but that will output an empty country array if no countries are selected and I'd prefer it not to appear at all if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        switch ($key)
        {
            case 'country':
                $country = Country::description($subvalue)->get()->first();
                if ($country) {
                    $result['country'][] = $country;
                }
                break;
            case 'gor':
                $gor = Gor::description($subvalue)->get()->first();
                if ($gor) {
                    $result['gor'][] = $gor;
                }
                break;
            case 'parlc':
                $parliamentaryconstituency = ParliamentaryConstituency::description($subvalue)->get()->first();
                if ($parliamentaryconstituency) {
                    $result['parliamentaryconstituency'][] = $parliamentaryconstituency;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

array_push always add a new element at the end of the array. Instead, initialize the array with all the keys like this

```
$result = array("country" => array(), "gor" => array(), etc);
```

And in your loop assuming the value you want to insert is in $value do

```
$result[$key][] = $value
```

Or if you prefer using array_push

```
array_push($result[$key], $value);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
'$list=array();'


/add array value
'array_push($list,array("name"=>"jone","surname"=>"doe"));'

//get array value
'$list[index][columnname]'
```